# Como puedo agregar este jquery en angular6 para realizar la paginación de una tabla

Tags: angularjs

```
      <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <th>N°</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Proceso</th>
          <th>Operaciones</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let proceso of procesoService.procesos">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>{{proceso._id}}</td>
            <td>{{proceso.Nombre_Proceso}}</td>
            <td id="ope">
                <a (click)="editProceso(proceso)" data-target="modal1" class=" modal-trigger ">
                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
              </a>
              <a  (click)="deleteProceso(proceso._id, procesoForm )">
                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>   
      <div class="pagination_wrapper" ng-app="paginator" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="chevron chevron-left"></li>
            <li (click)="paginacion()" ng-class="{ 'active': page.pageNumber === activePage }" ng-repeat="page in pageNumbers" ng-click="setActivePage($index)">{{ page.pageNumber }}</li>
            <li class="chevron chevron-right"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

<-componente proceso-->

```
paginacion(){
  $('paginator', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageNumbers = [
      {pageNumber: 1}, 
      {pageNumber: 2}, 
      {pageNumber: 3}, 
      {pageNumber: 4}, 
      {pageNumber: 5}
    ];

    $scope.activePage = 1;

    $scope.setActivePage = function(index) {
      $scope.activePage = index + 1;
    }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero deberías incluir la librería de JQuery en el index.html: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">`. En tu componente justo después de tus `imports`, debes agregar las siguientes variables: 

`declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;`

Luego justo después de tu OnInit colocas lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready({


});
```

Y dentro del mismo ingresar tu código JQuery que tienes. Recuerda que esto debes hacerlo en el `component.ts`